# Unable to create table in MySQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my code which shows error:
This is Netbeans code to connect my test database and create table in it named r

```
try{
  Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","tiger");
  Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
  String query = "create table r(s int);";
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  this.dispose();
  roll second = new roll(); 
  second.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
  lbl1.setText("Error1 in database connectivity");
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You neither close the connection nor the statement. This will lead to resource leaks and memory problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

instead use

```
 stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```